# numeric_limits of atomic types

Tags: c++11, c++14, atomic, stdatomic, numeric-limits

Suppose someAtomic is an std::atomic with an integral underlying type, such as atomic_uint16_t. I don't want to assume WHICH integral type, however, in particular code, so I want something to accomplish the following, which right now doesn't compile:

```
if (newVal > numeric_limits<decltype(someAtomic)>::max()) throw "newVal too large";
else someAtomic.store(newVal, memory_order_release);
```

It looks like at least in VC++2015 there are no numeric_limits specializations for atomic types even if their underlying types do have such specializations. What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct my_numeric_limits : std::numeric_limits<T>{};

template<class T>
struct my_numeric_limits<std::atomic<T>> : my_numeric_limits<T>{};
```

Then you can use `my_numeric_limits<SomeAtomic>::max()`.

This is less likely to violate (vague) parts of the standard than adding a specialization to `std::numeric_limits` that does not depend on a user-provided type.  In C++11, there were requirements that you specialize over "user defined types", and I am uncertain if this has been resolved if `std::atomic<int>` is user-defined or not.  I saw a fix proposal, but am uncertain if it went anywhere.

Regardless, this follows the principle of least surprise, and is just as efficient.  Messing around with things in the `std` namespace should only be done when the alternatives are impractical.

Get something wrong, and your code suddenly becomes ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  People checking your code are rightly scared.  People modifying your code have to not screw up.  `my_numeric_limits` is robust, safe, and resists error.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Standard allows (and encourages) you to add specializations to `std::numeric_limits` and you can do just that.

```
#include <limits>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class std::numeric_limits<std::atomic<T>> : public std::numeric_limits<T> {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::atomic<int>>::max();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're allowed to specialize standard templates with types from the standard library

Comment: I would be very surprised if this is allowed. Can you back up your claim?